# Transform vector coordinate to pixel coordinate

Tags: c#, 2d, autocad, ca, cad

I have some objects with vector (x,y) coordinate on CAD file.I convert that file to image . I want to know pixel coorinate on image file from (x,y). How to do that ?
Everyone can help me ?

I have some objects with vector (x,y) coordinate on CAD file.I convert that file to image . I want to know pixel coorinate on image file from (x,y). How to do that ?
Everyone can help me ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question. Your question is not clear and written properly.

Comment: If using a professional SDK is an option for you, try the Vector features of [LEADTOOLS SDKs](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats#vector). There's a C# project with the SDK's samples called the SVG demo, which can (among other things) load AutoCAD files and display the coordinates as you move the mouse over the displayed image. If you'd like to try it, you can download a free evaluation edition [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).